# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::put()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, php-7

I am developing a Laravel Application for poultry farm management.

And here I am using eloquent to return a collection of Stockegg table, which stores data about the egg stock.

But as total stock is not present in the Stockegg table, I am calculating it in a loop using the initial value of the total stock.

Here is the controller:

```
$stockeggs = \App\Stockegg::where('farm_id', '=', $farm)->orderBy('date', 'asc')->get();

$current_stock = $initial_stock;
foreach($stockeggs as $stockegg){
    $current_stock = $current_stock + $stockegg->daily_balance;
    $stockegg->put('total_stock', $current_stock);
}
```

But I get this error:

```
(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::put()
```

I have included the following line at the top of mu controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`put` is not method for Eloquent. You should write code something like this.

```
foreach($stockeggs as $stockegg){
    $current_stock = $current_stock + $stockegg->daily_balance;
    $stockegg->total_stock = $current_stock;
    $stockegg->save();
}
```

For more info https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#updates

Answer (score 2):

You have a collection which cotains `Stockegg` models so when you loop the collection, you have a single model which doesn't implement `put()` method.
So let's just add `total_stock` as attribute:

```
    $stockeggs = \App\Stockegg::where('farm_id', '=', $farm)->orderBy('date', 'asc')->get();

    $current_stock = $initial_stock;
    foreach($stockeggs as $stockegg){
        $current_stock = $current_stock + $stockegg->daily_balance;
        $stockegg->total_stock= $current_stock;
        $stockegg->update()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this:

```
$stockeggs = \App\Stockegg::where('farm_id', '=', $farm)->orderBy('date', 'asc')->get();

$current_stock = $initial_stock;
foreach($stockeggs as $stockegg){
    $current_stock = $current_stock + $stockegg->daily_balance;

    //Update total stock in stockegg table

    \App\Stockegg::where('id', '=', $stockegg->id)->update(array('total_stock'=>$current_stock));
}
```